# A weird limitation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am come up with this problem while conducting my research in statistical inference and triangular array. I am not sure it is correct or not. I run some simulations in MATLAB, for example, when $x_{i,n} = \frac{1}{n}$, and I observed that the result holds.

Problem. Given sequence $\{x_{i,n}\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ such that $x_{i,n} \in [0,1)$. Suppose that $x_{i,n} = o(1)$, where $o(1) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Consider the sequence $\{a_{i,n}\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ satisfying $a_{i,n} = 1 - (1-x^2_{i,n})^n$ for all $i =1,2, \dots, n$.  Prove that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,n} = 0$$.

Update: I just found an upper bound of $x_{i,n}$ by applying Stolze-Cesaro theorem so that the result will hold.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,n} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}a_{i,n} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{n}x^2_{i,n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-x^{2}_{i,n})^k\right) = 0$.

We have
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-x^{2}_{i,n})^k \leq n$. Hence, if we have $x_{i,n} < \frac{1}{n^{a}}$, where $\alpha > \frac{3}{2}$,  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}a_{i,n} = 0.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by $x_{i,n}=o(1)$  Are you saying that for each $i$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{i,n}\to0$?

Comment: Yep, I mean for each $i$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{i,n} = 0$. For example, $x_{i,n} = \frac{1}{n}, \forall i =1, 2, \dots, n.$

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let $x_{i,n}$ be 1 when $i>n-n^{.5}$ and 0 otherwise. For fixed $i$ and large enough $n$ this is $0$, so it solves your limiting condition.

Then, for a given $n$, $x_{i,n}$ is $1$ for around $n^{.5}$ terms and 0 for the rest. When it’s 0, $a_{i,n}$ is 0 and when it’s 1, $a_{i,n}$ is 1.

Therefore, the sum over $i$ for fixed $n$ is within one of $n^{.5}$, so your expression is $1$ in the limit and not 0.

You could tweak things so that the limit goes to infinity or isn’t defined at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I mean in my problem, $x_{i,n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $i$. May be I am wrong but I don't think your example satisfies this condition.

Comment: I found an upper bound for $x_{i,n}$ by applying Stolze -Cesaro theorem. It should satisfy that $x_{i,n} <\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$, where $\alpha > 3/4$.

Comment: My condition satisfies for all $i$ that $\lim_n x_{i,n} =0$. This new condition in your comment that $x_{i,n}< 1/n^{\alpha}$ is much stronger than your original problem.